# How to attach images in swiftmailer to embed them in twig mail template?

Tags: symfony, twig, swiftmailer

I want to use images in my mail template - they should be sent with the mail. How do I embed them in twig template (a special path or setting to address them?)? Do I attach them as an attachment or are there some special settings?

Comment: Have you tried something already before going to ask something here?

Comment: I'm in process now :)

Answer (score 14):

You can embed images into a Twig template by doing the following:

*(Below assumes you've already setup the relevant `Swift_Message` as `$message` and `$data` may contain other information that you're passing through to the Twig template)*

```
$data['image_src'] = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('path/to/image.jpg'));

$message->setBody(
    $this->templating->render('path/to/twigtemplate.html.twig', $data)
);
```

Then, inside your Twig template, you can use:

```
<img src="{{ image_src }}" alt="Image Description">
```

This will embed the image inline in the email to be sent out.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed elements while you are creating a body

[documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-dynamic-content)

Comment: I think this documentation is just about embedding in swiftmailer but I guess the question is about embedding elements in *twig template* through swiftmailer

Comment: Yeah, but in this case you can pass the generated url to template before tpl injection to body?